# Need some clarification for a currying argument

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I was reading some introductory theory on G-sets and G-actions and this theorem says that G-sets and G-actions have a very strong equivalence. So far so good. Then it uses a double currying and it's also my first time encountering the currying concept, so I'm confused on the logic behind the double curry. Here's what it has:

> $(1)$ The passage from a function of two variables  ∶  ×  ⟶  to a function of one variable  ∶  ⟶ $^$,  ⟼  (, −) is a standard operation called currying.

> Let  be a group. The following statements hold:
>
> 1. Let ( , ) be a ‐set. Then, the function
>
> $(2)$ $\bar{}$ ∶  ×  ⟶  , (, ) ⟼  ⋅  ∶= $_$ (), for $_\in$ Sym ()
>
> is an action of  on .
>
> 2. Let  be a set equipped with an action  ∶  ×  → . Then, the
>    function
>
> $(3)$ $\bar{}$ ∶  ⟶ Sym (),  ⟼ ((, −) ∶  ↦  ⋅ )
>
> is a group homomorphism, that is the pair ( , $\bar{}$) is a ‐set.
>
> 3. Show $\bar{\bar{}}=$ and $\bar{\bar{}}=$.

Here's what is written down as the proof and I add the superscript on the equal to identify the reason why I think the equality holds:

$\bar{\bar{}}_()=^{(1)}\bar{}(,)=^{(2)}_()$

$\bar{\bar{}}(,)=^{(2)}\bar{}_()=^{(1)}(,)$

My confusion is with $(2)$ and the notation. The (2) of  is by the definition and the $(2)$ of  is due to using the same tactics on the ‐set ( , $\bar{}$). Is the bar in (2) the same as the bar for currying used in (1) and (3)? Due to notation I'd think so, but I can't see why/how.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When writing MathJax formulas, its better to use the TeX commands for Greek letter symbols, for example `\mu`. Take a look at our [mathjax guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), particularly item 2 on the first page.

Comment: @LeeMosher is there a reason why we must write things in that way? Your link doesn't explain why I should write like that.

Comment: Who said you must? But, it's better, as I wrote. One reason its better is that `µ` is not portable but `\mu` is.

Comment: For example, if you ever have reason to write a $\LaTeX$ document you'll discover that `µ` is not an accepted character.

Comment: Yes, I have written in LaTeX and I'm familiar with some of the basic you showed. I just copied the text and theorem from the Pdf file and it came like that. Normally the math would break through copy paste, but this worked fine, so I kept it that way.

Comment: Going in the other direction, i.e. copy-pasting from the source of your post to a $\LaTeX$ document, would of course not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ambiguous, yes. I probably would not have written it that way myself. But it's written clearly enough nonetheless.

There are two different bars. They happen to look exactly alike, so, you have to look carefully at what kind of object that bar is sitting on top of, in order to determine which bar it is.

The first bar is defined in (2), and that's the bar that is put on top of a homomorphism like $\rho$ from $G$ to $\text{Sym}(X)$.

The second bar is defined in (3), and that's the bar that is put on top of an action function like $\mu$ from $G \times X$ to $X$.

For example, in the expression $\bar{\bar \rho}$, $\rho$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to $\text{Sym}(X)$, and so the bar in the sub-expression $\bar\rho$ is the one defined in (2). The effect is that $\bar\rho$ is an action from $G \times X$ to $X$. So, the top level bar in the expression $\bar{\bar\rho}$ is sitting on top of an action function from $G \times X$ to $X$, namely $\bar\rho$, and therefore that top level bar is the one defined in (3). Its effect is that $\bar{\bar\rho}$ is then a homomorphism from $G$ to $\text{Sym}(X)$.

Your goal is therefore to prove that $\rho$ and $\bar{\bar\rho}$ are the exact same homomorphism from $G$ to $\text{Sym}(X)$. I would suggest that the first line of your proof should be "Let $\mu=\bar\rho$. We must show that $\bar\mu=\rho$."